# Override PhoneNumber IdentityUser as ForeignKey .Net Core Web Api

Tags: rest, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've `PhoneNumber`is seperated entity in `Context` i need to assign it as foreign key to  `IdentityUser`
i was used `Guid` as Primary key but when i defined it as foreign key i found already they are field called `PhoneNumber`in `IdentityUser` class then i changed it to `string` to override the actual `PhoneNumber` field and i want to assign it to the `PhoneNumber` entity and use the field as ForeignKey then i set the `ForeignKey` Atrribute to the phoneNumber theni faced this error

> The ForeignKeyAttributes on property 'PhoneNumber' and navigation 'phoneNumber' in entity type 'User' do not point at each other. The value of ForeignKeyAttribute on property should be navigation name and the value of ForeignKeyAttribute on navigation should be the foreign key property name.

Here is `PhoneNumber Entity`

```
     public partial class PhoneNo
    {
        public PhoneNo()
        {
            User = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
       
        public string Prifix { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LineNo { get; set; }


        public ICollection<User>User{ get; set; }
        

    }
```

`UserEntity`

```
public class User:IdentityUser
   {
       
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string  MiddleName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string ProfilePict { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("phoneNumber")]
       public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("Identities")]
       public Guid IdentityId { get; set; }
       public Identities Identities { get; set; }
       public PhoneNo phoneNumber { get; set; }

   }
```

I've tried to remove `ForeignKey`Attribute but it creates other field called `PhoneNumberId` and the original field  both in `User`class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed `phoneNumber` Navigation to `phoneNo`and it's work ..

The new `phoneNumber`Navigation

```
public PhoneNo phoneNo { get; set; }
```

assigned `ForeignKey` Property

```
  [ForeignKey("phoneNo")]
    public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```